# Jquery Navigation Issue

Tags: jquery, navigation

I am trying to get this code to work for me,but It is not working properly. I am trying to have two separate red lines work with my two ULs simultaneously. Instead there is just one line that jumps across the two lists.

I am also not sure how to have the text change color when the link is clicked and the line is positioned under it.

http://jsfiddle.net/MWaer/

It also has a bug where if you click on one link more than once the red line moves back to the previous link and wont stay on the link clicked.

I originally found the code here http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/

Does anyone know what is going on? I would appreciate any help anyone can give.

Comment: As your code doesn't work its hard to tell what you want. It also looks like you just cut and pasted the code twice and hoped it would work. Try adding just one line that works the way you want it to and ask someone to help you get it working for a second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest thing to do when you hit a snag editing code from someplace else is to start over. Start with their code and slowly alter it step by step rather than trying to just throw something at all your code.

Here's part of the way there... since I don't know exactly what your'e trying to accomplish, I merely focused on getting the two lines to work. [**Updated Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/MWaer/2/)